# How can I compute the derivative of a modular form, for example an Eisenstein series?

Tags: modular-forms

Suppose that $f(z)$ is a modular form of weight $k$, therefore for any $z\in \mathbb{H}$, and any matrix in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ we have:
$$f\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right) = (cz+d)^k f(z).$$ I do not know how to use this relation to compute the derivative of $f$. Now let $G_{2k}$ be an Eisenstein series of weight $2k$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series). How can I compute derivates of $E_4$ and $E_6$ in terms of Eisenstein series? Starting from $$G_{2k}\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right) = (cz+d)^{2k} G_{2k}(z),$$ I can just find this immediate relation $$\left(\frac{1}{cz+d}\right)^2G'_{2k}\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right) = (cz+d)^{2k} G'_{2k}(z)+2kc(cz+d)^{2k-1} G_{2k}(z).$$ How can I calculate the derivative of $j$-invariant?

Comment: Note that $\,q := \exp(2\pi i\,z)\,$ and the chain rule implies that $\,f'(z) = 2\pi i \,q\, df(q)/dq\,$ which uses the $q$-series expansion of $\,f(z).\,$ An example is [OEIS sequence A004009](https://oeis.org/A004009) "Expansion of Eisenstein series E_4(q)".

Comment: By the way, the answer to your question about the derivative of $\,j\,$ is mentioned in [OEIS sequence A035230](https://oeis.org/A035230).